# Update one column values with another column values using variables

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a query:

```
`UPDATE table1 SET column1 = coulmn2;`
```

Here, column1 values will be updated as column2 values.

But, I am writing a PROCEDURE in which I want to update column values as above, inside a loop where I pass column names through string variables.

E.g.

```
`str1 varchar(50) := 'column1';`
`str2 varchar(50) := 'column2';`
`str3 varchar(200) := 'update table1 set' + str1 + '=' + str2;`
`execute immediate str3;`
```

But, here the query is executed as: column1 = 'column2'
All the values in column1 are updated by 'column2' string and not by values of column2.

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the SQL statement as a string, then execute it using "execute immediate";

```
create procedure ...
  sql_txt varchar2(32000)
begin
  sql_txt := ...;
  execute immediate sql_txt;
end;
```

Comment: I have already done that in my code above. My problem is, from my code, str1 is being taken as column name but, str2 is being taken as string and not column name. I want str2 also to be interpreted as column name.

Comment: If you run DBMS_Output to view the SQL that you're constructing, you'll see where the error(s) is/are. For example, you have no space between "set" and the following single quote, so actually you're constructing a SQL statement "update table1 setcolumn1=column2", so I doubt that the code you list is even running.

Comment: Please assume that there are no syntax errors. I am bothered about the logic. The query is running but, I am not achieving what I am intending to do. I hope you understood, what I am trying to say. Have you actually understood what the query is doing ??

Comment: If str2 is being taken as a string and not as a column name then that is a matter of syntax. What does your actual generated SQL statement look like

Comment: Yes. So, I want a resolution for str2 to be taken as a column name and not as string value.

Comment: I asked what your actual SQL statement looks like.